# Creating cartoon animations

Tags: animation

I hope this is the right place to put this but here goes.

I was watching this trailer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZXyxZK28QY

When i wondered how they made it. I have seen this style in a anime called Terror in resonance and other games. 
but i was just wondering how it is done or what programs were used for this.

I have also seen something like that here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEqTmym-Dds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is a site dedicated to Blender 3D, I suspect that the questions is **"Are these kinds of animations doable in blender?"**

If so, the answer is yes.

You might want to do a google search for tutorials on "Non Photorealistic Rendering in Blender" (Or "NPR rendering") and "Blender Freestyle"

[image]
Tire Bike by Pro Creaciones. CC BY

> Freestyle is an edge- and line-based non-photorealistic (NPR) rendering engine. It relies on mesh data and z-depth information to draw lines on selected edge types. Various line styles can be added to produce artistic (“hand drawn”, “painted”, etc.) or technical (hard line) looks.

Here are some links that illustrate some of the possible uses for freesyle:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/FreeStyle#Freestyle_Artwork_Showcase

To get started [Read this link](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/render/freestyle/index.html) to the blender manual

Comment: Would i be able to-do the things done in the first trailer

Comment: That monowheel: you cannot brake, you cannot see, WEHEE!

Answer (score 1):

The first video is a **cut-out animation**. This technique can be achieved in Blender by rigging textured planes.

Regarding the setting, those planes are distributed in 3D space to achieve depth. This is enhanced by the use of depth of field through a perspective camera and other effects.

A recent example is Nikolai Mamashev's rig inspired in the comic Pepper&Carrot by David Revoy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9N3D2RisH0

This covers at least the character animation. Effects such as smoke, particles, and image post-processing can also be composited in Blender.

The second video might be a **vector animation**. Here the assets are drawn in a vectorial software. Even though the technique is similar to cut-out, it also allows to keyframe the vectors for a smooth animation such as the one for the hair.

As far as I know, this could not be achieved in Blender as easily as the previous example. If you are looking for a Free Software package for the task, I recommend Synfig.

Comment: It's worth mentioning too that there are other alternatives in blender to do hand drawn animation using the grease pencil: https://vimeo.com/channels/greasepencil/140485204